# Sort a Grouped query

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using the following query to display a list of months for which my database has data.

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, EVENT_DATE) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, EVENT_DATE) AS MonthYear
FROM [ODA].[dbo].[REPORT_CASE_EXT]
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, EVENT_DATE) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, EVENT_DATE)
```

If I add the following sort to the query, I get an error because they don't appear in the groupby

```
SORT BY DATENAME(YEAR, EVENT_DATE), DATENAME(MONTH, EVENT_DATE)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would "work" if you would use the same in the `ORDER BY` as in the `GROUP BY`.

```
ORDER BY
    DATENAME(MONTH, EVENT_DATE) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, EVENT_DATE)
```

But you need to add  more informations to the `GROUP BY` to be able to order in chronological order instead of alphabetically(otherwise February is before January):

```
GROUP BY
    datename(YEAR, EVENT_DATE),
    datename(MONTH, EVENT_DATE),
    datepart(YEAR, EVENT_DATE),
    datepart(MONTH, EVENT_DATE)
ORDER BY
    datepart(YEAR, EVENT_DATE),
    datepart(MONTH, EVENT_DATE)
```